# Looking for a short story with two gay (?) guys in an end of the world scenario, one sells the other out

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a short story I read some time ago in one of my literature classes, but I can't remember where I left it.

Like the title suggests, it’s about two guys (I vaguely remember that one was younger than the other) who were kind of lovers, or at least were in FWB situation. It is established that they lived in the aftermath of a nuclear war or something that destroyed the world, so rations and water are measured. There's this group that kind of controls rations, but the youngest has either stolen or hidden away a stash of fresh water, because the oldest always loves that he showers and smells good and what not.

At the end of the story, the old guy has settled up the youngest to admit that he has indeed hidden away the water, and is planning to sell out his lover so that the group that controls everything will give him something.

That's all that I can remember, I'll thank forever anyone who can lead me on the right direction!